# sscanf can't read last line of the text file

Tags: c, io, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1001];
    char name[15], surname[30];
    float mid1, mid2, final, avg;

    fp = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("Could not open file. Program finished.");
        return 0;
    }

    fgets(buffer, 1000, fp);

    while (feof(fp) == 0)
    {
        sscanf(buffer, "%s%s%f%f%f", name, surname, &mid1, &mid2, &final);

        printf("%s %s %f %f %f\n", name, surname, mid1, mid2, final);

        fgets(buffer, 1000, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my text file,

```
Ali Veli 67 80 76
Ahmet Mehmet 45 64 63
Ayse Fatma 89 98 83
```

all the things okay but it can't read last line of the text file
in the output "Ayse Fatma 89 98 83" it can't printing.

Comment: Looks more like C than C++. Please choose one language. Also worth a read: [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Who taught you to use `while(feof(fp) == 0)`?

Comment: http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~neff/teaching/CWebsite/fileReading.html

Comment: Failure to open the file would typically be considered an error.  Hence, `if(!fp) {perror("grades.txt"); return EXIT_FAILURE;}`.  Write the error message to stderr, include the reason, and return a failure status.

Comment: Although not well structured, the code should read the last line — if the data file has a newline at the end.  If the final newline is missing, it is possible that `feof()` reports EOF too soon.  The recommended restructuring avoids some possible pitfalls.  You could also print the line that you parse to see whether there is a newline: `printf("Line: [[%s]]\n", buffer);` after the `fgets()` calls.  But you should really check the result of `fgets()` before using the value in `buffer`, hence the restructured version is better (no repetition) and you'd place the `printf()` before the `sscanf()`.

Comment: @BatuhanGunes Good to have post [source](http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~neff/teaching/CWebsite/fileReading.html) of weak code.  Take that into consideration for other code examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use the value that `fgets` returns as a condition of your `while` cycle:

```
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
{
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%14s%29s%f%f%f", name, surname, &mid1, &mid2, &final) == 5)
        printf("%s %s %f %f %f\n",name,surname,mid1,mid2,final);
}
```

The cycle will stop when there are no more lines to read from the file.

Also, a good practice is to always check `*scanf` return.

Limiting `"%s"` specifiers size to their buffer is also recommended, this will avoid buffer overflow, in this case `"%14s"` and `"%29s"` for 15 char and 30 char buffer respectively, size - 1 relates to the need to reserve a space for the null terminator.

You should also follow the link in [@pzaenger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62262664/sscanf-cant-read-last-line-of-the-text-file/62262816#comment110116673_62262664) regarding the use of `while(feof(fp) == 0)`.